# Return from a function in Pascal

Tags: pascal

Giving the following function in Pascal where `GetChar` is another function. How is `GetChar` executed after the function returns with the := operator?

```
function GetNum: char;
begin
   GetNum := Look;
   GetChar;
end;
```

Answer (score 5):

The assignment in Pascal doesn't return, it is just an assignment.  So GetChar will be executed.

Comment: The assignment to GetNum sets the value that the function will return, it does not cause the function to return, so the call to GetChar will be executed.